# How can I mutate fields of a struct while referencing other fields?

Tags: rust

Here's an example of a problem I ran into:

```rust
pub struct Item {
  name: String,
  value: LockableValue, // another struct that I'd like to mutate
}
impl Item {
  pub fn name(&self) -> &str {
    &self.name
  }

  pub fn value_mut(&mut self) -> &mut LockableValue {
    &self.value
  }
}

pub fn update(item: &mut Item) {
  let value = item.value_mut();
  value.change(); // how it changes is unimportant
  println!("Updated item: {}", item.name());
}
```

Now, I know *why* this fails. I have a mutable reference to item through the mutable reference to the value.

If I convert the reference to an owned String, it works fine, but looks strange to me:

```rust
pub fn update(item: &mut Item) {
  let name = { item.name().to_owned() };

  let value = item.value_mut();
  value.change(); // how it changes is unimportant
  println!("Updated item: {}", name); // It works!
}
```

If I let value reference drop, then everything is fine.

```rust
pub fn update(item: &mut Item) {
  {
    let value = item.value_mut();
    value.change(); // how it changes is unimportant
  }
  println!("Updated item: {}", item.name()); // It works!
}
```

The `value.change()` block is rather large, and accessing other fields in item might be helpful. So while I do have solutions to this issue, I'm wondering if there is a better (code-smell) way to do this. Any suggestions?

My intention behind the above structs was to allow `Item`s to change values, but the name should be immutable. `LockableValue` is an tool to interface with another memory system, and copying/cloning the struct is not a good idea, as the memory is managed there. (I implement `Drop` on `LockableValue` to clean up.)

I was hoping it would be straight-forward to protect members of the struct from modification (even if it were immutable) like this... and I can, but it ends up looking weird to me. Maybe I just need to get used to it?

Comment: There must be more to this issue than what can be seen in your snippets (I assume your claim "how it changes is unimportant" is not true here). This works perfectly fine: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=14dd508c52add134ff750ecb26c9767e

Comment: Rust **can** figure out when to drop no longer used value without the brackets, too. As it's written, the problem is not reproducible. Please include the original error message as well as a snippet of code that exhibits the stated error.

Comment: The problem was less around "why is this failing?" and more around "I'm running into an error here because I'm borrowing an immutable ref when I already have a ref, how to do it better?".

Comment: Maybe you're using an ultra-old version of Rust. What is your version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use interior mutability on only the part that you want to mutate by using a `RefCell` like ths:

```rust
use std::cell::{RefCell, RefMut};
pub struct LockableValue;
impl LockableValue {
    fn change(&mut self) {}
}
pub struct Item {
    name: String,
    value: RefCell<LockableValue>, // another struct that I'd like to mutate
}
impl Item {
    pub fn name(&self) -> &str {
        &self.name
    }

    pub fn value_mut(&self) -> RefMut<'_, LockableValue> {
        self.value.borrow_mut()
    }
}

pub fn update(item: &Item) {
    let name = item.name();
    let mut value = item.value_mut();
    value.change(); // how it changes is unimportant
    println!("Updated item: {}", name);
}
```

That way you only need a shared reference to `Item` and you don't run into an issue with the borrow checker.

Not that this forces the borrow checks on `value` to be done at runtime though and thus comes with a performance hit.

Comment: Thank you, I'll need to dive on RefCell and see how much of a hit that might be.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need to use RefCell here. see [borrowing](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/expressions/field-expr.html#borrowing)

> The fields of a struct or a reference to a struct are treated as separate entities when borrowing

so you should be able to mut borrow `value` while having a immutable reference to `name`. This works when I change name type to String.

```rust
pub struct Item {
    name: String,
    value: String, // another struct that I'd like to mutate
}
impl Item {
    pub fn name(&self) -> &str {
        &self.name
    }

    pub fn value_mut(&mut self) -> &mut String {
        &mut self.value
    }
}

pub fn update(item: &mut Item) {
    let value = item.value_mut();
    let _ = value.insert(0, 'a'); // insert take a &mut String
    println!("Updated item: {}", item.name());
}
```

So I suspect there is some property of `LockableValue` that is different here. Or you may be using a very old version of Rust. Maybe you can give a little more details?